# jquery validator error position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using the "jQuery form validator" (formvalidator.net) in combination with the "jQuery tabs widget" (api.jqueryui.com/tabs).

I'm trying to have more control on where the error message is displayed, because now it is distroying my layout.

I'm new on this forum, and seem not to find how you can attach some files, that's why I copied them on http://www.petravancaneghem.be/tseries/index.html. If you just tab through the input field without entering any data, you'll see what I mean with "destroying my layout".

Solutions I’m looking for:

- Put the error text underneath the item (like in the demo page of the validator) – didn’t find how to do that in the documentation
- Have absolute error messages popping up, which are then able to show even out of my tab container.
- Put error messages all together underneath my tab area – I know there is an option to put them above, but I would prefer below in a separate scrollable container (avoids excessive vertical size)

I looked in this forum for a solution, and somebody came up with using the construction `$.validate({errorElement: "div"});`, which I did use on my html page (see my index.html). But this doesn't seem to have any effect.

I hope to find a solution here.

Comment: Did you tried http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator?
It won't disrupt any web page styles/layouts

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you

```
   //line 125 i think, add height as auto !important
  .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
     display: block;
     border-width: 0;
     padding: 1em 1.4em;
    background: none;
    height: auto !important;
      }

  //add this style, it styles your error mgs

     .form-error.help-block {
      display: block;
      clear: both;
       margin-left: 178px;
       color: red;
      }
```